# What Cipher Suites to use with OpenSSL 1.1.1 for TLSv1.3?

Tags: ssl, security, apache-2.4, iis, openssl

What cipher suites to use with OpenSSL 1.1.1 for TLSv1.3?

I really want it to be AES56 or CHACHA20.

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html I think it couldn't be more clearer than "TLS v1.3 cipher suites"

Answer (score -3):

Do this:

Cipher Suites:

For TLSv1.2:

Apache:

ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384

ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305

ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

IIS 10:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

For TLSv1.3:

nano /ect/openssl/openssl.conf

Add this line:

Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

This is not compliant with RFC 8446 section 9.1 but better.

Comment: Alle but the information about `Ciphersuites` are irrelevant here since they don't apply to TLS 1.3, which was specifically asked about in the question And some don't even apply to Apache, which was also explicitly asked about.  And if you are claiming that disabling mandatory cipher suites (which you correctly refer to) is better than you should at least provide an explanation for this claim.